# i am having a problem with using jakarta mail :The import jakarta cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-mail

the ide displays an error(The import jakarta cannot be resolved) when trying to import any of the jakarta libraries to the class:
`import jakarta.mail.*; import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress; import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;`
all gets me the same error

i tried instaling the jars manually, everything was done the right way, but the ide (i am using ecipse) cant import the libraries to the class idk why,
got tired of this and installed maven to my project, and tried using jakarta 1.6.7 and 2.smth
and also everything was working fine untill i try to import the libraries to the class, even tho that the pom file have the jakarta dependency and is displaying no errors..

Comment: Jars on the classpath can be expanded and explored just like folders when using the Package and Project Explorer views. Is the package name really the problem? Have you verified that these types actually present?

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules). Otherwise, please say exactly what you did (be aware that there are different ways to do) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a Java version issue. Prior to Java 17 `jakarta.mail` was `javax.mail`.

Either upgrade to Java17 which have `jakarta.mail` api built in, or

Use Java11 or less with `javax.mail`.

Comment: `javax.mail` is not in Java SE.  It is in Java EE.   Upgrading to Java 17 will make no difference.

Comment: i am now using jdk-17 and i am still having the same problem, should i stop using maven for it to work?

Comment: Please add your pom/gradle file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Mail APIs are part of Java EE / Jakarta EE not Java SE.

Up to Java EE 8 (2017-08-31), the package name was `javax.email`.  It remained that in Jakarta EE 8 (2019-09-10) it remained the same.  In Jakarta EE 9 (2020-12-08) the package name changed to `jakarta.mail`.

For reasons that I haven't researched, the Jakarta Mail spec version numbers don't align with the Java EE / Jakarta EE version numbers.  The current specifications are [Jakarta Mail 2.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/2.0/) and [Jakarta Mail 2.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/2.1/), and the corresponding Maven coordinates are

- `jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:jar:2.0.1` and
- `jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:jar:2.1.0`

If you already have one of those dependencies in your POM file, then the next thing to look at is why your IDE is not adding those JARs to the project classpath.

Comment: ideed i am using java se not java ee, i think this might be the problem, since i installed the jars and a added jakarta as a maven dependency all while having javaSE, if you will excuse the newbie question.. how do i migrate from java se to java ee?

Comment: You don't migrate from Java SE to EE.  Java SE is provided by your Java installation.  The Java EE implementation is typically provided your web container; e.g. Tomcat, WebSphere, GlassFish, etc.  They all depend on Java SE.

Comment: Like I said, if you have one of the dependencies that I listed, then the problem is in your IDE / Maven integration or something.  Or maybe the IDE or Maven has the wrong Java (SE) version selected.